# C++ - Submenu is not working

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, submenu

Currently I'm trying to create a menu for my WIN32 program.
Unfortunately I'm not able to create a submenu in it.
Here's my code:

```
HMENU menu = CreateMenu();
HMENU mFile = CreatePopupMenu();

AppendMenu(menu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)mFile, L"File");
AppendMenu(mFile, MF_STRING, NULL, L"Exit");

SetMenu(hwnd, menu);
```

The menu itself is displayed as expected, but when I click on "File" nothing happens.
Nevertheless there should appear a submenu when I click on File.
Can anybody explain me what's the reason that this code doesn't work?

**Edit**: @IInspectable Thank you for your suggestion! I checked the return value and it's 0, so the function failed. Suprisingly the following code works:

```
HMENU menu = CreateMenu();
HMENU mFile = CreatePopupMenu();

AppendMenu(menu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)mFile, L"File");
AppendMenu(mFile, MF_STRING, NULL, L"Exit");

MessageBox(hwnd, L"An error occured.", L"Error!", MB_OK);

SetMenu(hwnd, menu);
```

I have no idea why it is working with this code, but now the submenu is showing up when I click "File".
Is there any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for the missing greeting, but unfortunately I'm not able to add one, because the change is just ignored.

Comment: [See why here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950).

Comment: [AppendMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647616.aspx) has a return value. This is the sort of information you should be interested in.

Comment: Don't you need to pass the top-level `HMENU` to `CreateSubMenu`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out what caused the dropdown menu to not show up when I clicked it. A little akward, to be honest, but I set the extended window style to `WS_EX_NOACTIVATION`. If you replace it with any other, the menu shows up.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It works on my system. However, the design is "sort of" incorrect.

`mFile` should be a regular menu. Any sub-menus after that are regular menus as well, unless they are parent menus themselves..

Example:

[image: Example 1]

```
#define EXIT_ID 1

case WM_CREATE:
{
    HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu(); //file is a regular menu.. Exit is a regular sub-menu..

    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, "File"); //create file menu.
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, EXIT_ID, "Exit");  //regular menu. Has no children.
    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);
}
break;
```

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]

```
#define EXIT_ID 1
#define SUB_ID 2

case WM_CREATE:
{
    HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu(); //file is a regular menu.. Exit is a regular sub-menu..
    HMENU hDisplayMenu = CreatePopupMenu(); //display is a popup-menu because it has children.

    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, "File");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hDisplayMenu, "Display"); //popup menu. Has children.
    AppendMenu(hDisplayMenu, MF_STRING, SUB_ID, "Sub"); //regular menu. Has no children.
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, EXIT_ID, "Exit"); //regular menu. Has no children.
    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);
}
break;
```